# Can I reinstall Ubuntu from an ext HDD image after loading Win7 onto the formerly Ubuntu laptop, and get a working dual boot system? If so, how

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I want to set up a dual-boot Win7 + Ubuntu system on a current Ubuntu Linux DELL laptop  The Windows 7 Ultimate disk I have is a DELL reinstall only disk, so it will wipe any existing OS on the system.  Can I copy the Ubuntu Linux setup as an image to an external HDD, then load Win7 onto the laptop, then copy the Ubuntu image back from the ext HDD, and wind up with a working dual boot system?  If so, are there any specific steps/sequence of steps to follow or specific pitfalls to watch out for?  If there is a better alternate process that has worked for you, I'm open to trying that instead.